# Elasticsearch : Expected field name but got START_OBJECT "more_like_this"

Tags: elasticsearch

All my Elasticsearch queries are working fine except when I am using the "more_like_this" feature, I allways get the "Expected field name but got START_OBJECT 'more_like_this'" error.

Here is my "array" with a regular query : (that is working fine)

```
Array
(
    [index] => videos
    [from] => 0
    [size] => 75
    [body] => Array
        (
            [query] => Array
                (
                    [bool] => Array
                        (
                            [must] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [match] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [gender] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [match_phrase] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [title] => my super title
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [range] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [date] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [lte] => 1525258744
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [sort] => Array
                (
                    [date] => Array
                        (
                            [order] => desc
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

And here is one with the more_like_this option : (that dont work)

```
Array
(
    [index] => videos
    [from] => 0
    [size] => 75
    [body] => Array
        (
            [query] => Array
                (
                    [bool] => Array
                        (
                            [must] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [match] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [gender] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [range] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [date] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [lte] => 1525258700
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [more_like_this] => Array
                        (
                            [fields] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => title
                                )

                            [like_text] => my super title
                            [min_term_freq] => 1
                            [max_query_terms] => 12
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: `more_like_this` should be located inside your `must` array

Comment: You are right, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer (thank to @Val), more_like_this should be part of the must array :

```
Array
(
    [index] => videos
    [from] => 0
    [size] => 75
    [body] => Array
        (
            [query] => Array
                (
                    [bool] => Array
                        (
                            [must] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [match] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [gender] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [more_like_this] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [fields] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => title
                                                        )

                                                    [like_text] => my super title
                                                    [min_term_freq] => 1
                                                    [max_query_terms] => 12
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [range] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [date] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [lte] => 1525269403
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```